# FSharp.Data extract a subset of columns from a CsvFile and write to new file

Tags: f#, f#-data

In F# (prob with FSharp.Data), how do I extract a subset of columns from a `CsvFile`?

For example, suppose I have a csv file `file1.csv`:

```
a, b, c, d
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
```

and want to read, keep only columns `a` and `b`, then write them to a new csv file. I would hope to use something like `Map`:

```
let originalCsvFile = CsvFile.Load("file1.csv")
let subset = originalCsvFile.Map(fun row -> <get columns a and b>) ... write to file("file2.csv")
```

but do not know what `fun` I should use nor how to write as a new file.

I can see from the types that the `fun` should return a `CsvRow` but I am unable to get further than this.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example will help people to answer.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html) for examples of how to extract data from the loaded CSV file.

Comment: I think if you repost the question again with the new clarification that you added, then it will not be closed again - you added enough detail and it's now clear what you're asking (but alas, I cannot answer closed question...).

Comment: One last upvote was missing to reopen this one

Comment: Hmm, hope this gets reopened at some point ... we got the votes for it.

Comment: Horrible formatting, semicolons are line breaks: type Csv = CsvProvider<"./test.csv">;
let csv = Csv.GetSample().Rows |> Seq.map (fun r -> sprintf "%i, %i" r.A r.B);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("test2.csv",csv);

Comment: you need one more vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CsvProvider` supports 'inline' schema specification. Once you have both file types you can map file1 rows to file2 rows, create a new File2 instance and save the new rows to a file:

```
open FSharp.Data

type File1 = CsvProvider<"file1.csv">
type File2 = CsvProvider<"a,b", Schema = "int,int">

let rows =
    File1.Load("file1.csv").Rows
    |> Seq.map(fun r -> File2.Row(r.A, r.B))
let f2 = new File2(rows)
f2.Save("file2.csv")
```